# Mail is going out 3 times instead of once to each address?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have come up with something which seems weird to me and I am not sure what exactly to search for.

```
import smtplib, openpyxl, sys
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx') 
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')    

lastCol = sheet.max_column  
latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

recipients = []
unpaidMembers = {}   
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=lastCol).value
if payment != 'Y':
    name = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
    email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
    unpaidMembers[name] = email
    recipients.append(email)

fromaddr = "xxxx@xxxx.com"

for n in recipients:
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = n
    msg['Subject'] = "Hi"

    body = "This is a test mail"

    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    filename = "xxx.pdf"
    attachment = open("\\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx.pdf","rb")

    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

    msg.attach(part)

    smtp0bj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
    smtp0bj.ehlo()
    smtp0bj.starttls()
    smtp0bj.login(fromaddr, 'xxxxx')
    text = msg.as_string()
    smtp0bj.sendmail(fromaddr, recipients, text)
    smtp0bj.quit()
```

I am guessing that the for-loop is being executed 3 times(there are 3 items in the list. I am at a loss about how to make it execute only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically do that :

```
for n in recipients: # for each recipient
    smtp0bj.sendmail(fromaddr, recipients, text) # send mail to all recipients
```

So at each pass it sends the mail to all the recipients.

So if you have 3 recipients, they'll receive 3 mails each.

Replace with :

```
smtp0bj.sendmail(fromaddr, n, text)
```

Also I'm not sure, and can't test right now, but I believe 'to' has to be a list.
So if the above solution doesn't work, give this a shot :

```
smtp0bj.sendmail(fromaddr, [n], text)
```

Comment: Thanks. :) I should have caught that.

The first solution worked perfectly.

Comment: simple mistakes are usually tough to debunk ;)